# When to release the coroutine resources in android service?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service, kotlin-coroutines, jobintentservice

I am using kotlin coroutines in my `JobIntentService`, So on `onHandleWork` I would launch my coroutine, once this tasks end, I need to clean up the resources by cancelling the `Job`. `onDestroy` called immediately after starting of the service, Since I am launching the coroutine on the `onHandleWork` it doesn't block the current thread.

> Is it mandatory to cancel the coroutine after finishing the task ?
>
> If so, When to release the coroutine resources in the android `Service` lifecycle

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

> is it mandatory to cancel the coroutine after finishing the task ?

No, it is not mandatory. Usually coroutines [are launched](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html#your-first-coroutine) in a context of some `CoroutineScope` and `CoroutineScope` is tied to some lifecycle, usually `Activity` or `Fragment`. Coroutines are used to execute some task in a background thread in a sequential manner.

Method `onHandleWork` of `JobIntentService` class [is called on a background thread](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService#onHandleWork(android.content.Intent)), so you can do long blocking operations here. I don't see the reason why you should launch a coroutine in this method. Just execute your task without launching the coroutine.

> Since i am launching the coroutine on the `onHandleWork` it doesn't block the current thread.

Method `onHandleWork` is called on a background thread so you don't need to launch a coroutine there.